# Real big noobie here, how to use mysql so I can edit multiple pages easily?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So right now, I've got a "gallery" system on my homepage of my site. Take a look:

```
<?php
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("mydb.db","hello","mypass") or die(mysql_error());
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydb");
        $pic2 = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
        if (!isset($_GET['Page']))  $_GET['Page']='0';
        $pic1 = mysql_query($pic2);
        $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($pic1);
        $Per_Page = 16;   // Per Page
        $Page = $_GET["Page"];
        if(!$_GET["Page"])
        {$Page=1;}
        $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
        $Next_Page = $Page+1;
        $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
        if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
        {$Num_Pages =1;}
        else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
        {$Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;}
        else
        {$Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
            $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;}
        $pic2 .=" order  by GalleryID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $pic1  = mysql_query($pic2);
$cell = 0;
$link2 = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
$link1 = mysql_query($link2);
$link = mysql_fetch_array($link1);
$alt2 = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
$alt1 = mysql_query($alt2);
$alt = mysql_fetch_array($alt1);
echo '<div id="tablediv"><table border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0" class="table"><tr>';
while($pic = mysql_fetch_array($pic1))
{if($cell % 4 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';}
if($cell == 2) {
    echo '<td>reserved cell, ignore this</td>';
} elseif ($cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>reserved cell, ignore this</td>';
} else {
    echo '
    <td><a href="/' . $link["link"] . '.php"><div class="image"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $pic["pic"] . '" alt="' . $alt["alt"] . ' /></div></a></td>'; }
    $cell++;
}
echo '</tr></table></div>';
    ?>
```

My table would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `thumbnailID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `alt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`thumbnailID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;

INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', 'stars/beezlebub', 'beezlebub', 'this is beezlebub');
INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', 'nature/raretree', 'raretree', 'this is a rare tree');
INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', 'nature/lions', 'lions', 'these are lions');
INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', 'nature/tigers', 'tigers', 'these are tigers');
etc. (you get the point)
```

Anyhow... as you can see, with this system, whenever I insert a new record, it automatically updates my gallery. Now my question is how can I make it so when I insert a new record, it doesn't just affect my homepage gallery, it affects the galleries on the other subsections of my website as well. Not sure what I mean? Here's an example:

Say my site is called site.com . I also have subfolders for site.com, which include site.com/nature and site.com/stars . I want my site.com/nature to contain a gallery for only star photos and my site.com/stars to be a gallery for only star photos, while my homepage contains all images, including the nature and stars photos. but I don't want to manually update /nature or /stars by creating extra tables. Instead, I just want to use one huge table, which contains all the images on my site, but make it so I can specify whether I want my record to also display (/nature, /stars, etc) and not just home (which contains all images).

I presume I would need another column (obviously) for specifying what other folders do I want my record to appear in, or maybe some conditional statements to determine which subfolder should my record also appear in and not just my homepage. Unfortunately, I'm a nooblet, so I'm asking if anyone can lend a hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, here is how I would structure this table, to make this correction:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `thumbnailID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `folderID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `alt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (thumbnailID))
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Notice the out-dented row...

Edit ***
Sorry didn't include the part about inserting. Here is the SQL you would run to insert a picture under, say, "nature":

```
INSERT INTO `images` (
`thumbnailID`, `folderID`, `link`, `pic`, `alt`, `time`
) VALUES (
NULL, 'nature', 'some link', 'some picture', 'some alt text', 'some timestamp'
)
```

Notice that "thumbnailID" is blank, since MySQL will automatically fill it in, since it is the primary key.

End Edit ***

When you run your SQL in a specific folder, such as the "nature" folder, here is how you would, basically, pull all data categorized under "nature":

```
SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `folderID` = 'nature' ORDER BY `thumbnailID` ASC;
```

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: Veryyyyy nice ^^, thanks a lot! I'm gonna wait here for a little more to see if any one's got a better idea heh.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct.  The quick, easy way is to create another column.

But, what you should really do is create another *table*, called `sections` or something like that.  It should look like this:

```
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | stars   |
| 2  | nature  |
...
```

And the new column you put into your main table would point to the `id` column of this table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| thumbnailID | link       | pic       | alt         | sectionID |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | ...        | raretree  | this is ... | 2         |
...
```

The last column there, `sectionID`, refers to the second item in table `sections`.

Next, create a folder called `/section/`, and create a new PHP page in it called `section.php`.  Lets say you want to view a section like this:

`http://example.com/section/section.php?section=nature`

You get the section with `$_GET['section']`, and do a SQL `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `sections` JOIN `images` ON `images`.`sectionID` = `sections`.`id` WHERE `sections`.`name` = {section}
```

Put the value of `$_GET['section']` in place of `{section}`

You can even change it so that sections are accessed like this:

`http://example.com/section/nature`

With `mod_rewrite`.

http://www.snipe.net/2009/02/practical-mod_rewrite/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)

http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/mysql-join-tutorial.14876.html

Comment: While this seems really intuitive I must ask why do all that? Spryno's method seems easier, more SEO friendly with clean url (I really am just curious, and would definitely consider it if there is a good gain)

Comment: @user657847: Number 1, duplicate data.  Number 2, it allows you to have a fixed (but dynamic) set of sections.  It means you can easily add a new section to the database, and that's it.  No creating new folders, nothing.  There are probably more reasons, but can't think of them now.  And it's not "less SEO friendly": see the part about `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 2):

Will an image in your gallery ever belong to two or more sections? Or will the image only ever belong in one gallery? I'm assuming images can exist in many galleries, since an image may be of stars and nature.

If they can be cross posted, then you need another two tables.

```
Images 
Folders(id, name)
Images_Folders(image_id, folder_id)
```

Then you don't need to change your Images table. Just make sure that when something is 'tagged', that you insert an entry into Images_Folders appropriately.

To get all images for stars, you'd do:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM images i
JOIN images_folders if ON i.id = if.image_id
JOIN folders f on f.id = if.folder_id
WHERE folder_name = 'stars'
```

Edit:
Tagging just means that an image is said to belong to a particular group or folder. So, if a user uploads a folder (or you do), it will exist in the images table. To 'tag' it, you'd do an insert to the `images_folder` table.

```
$folder = 'stars';
$image_id = 4;

INSERT INTO images_folder (image_id, folder_id)
SELECT image_id = $image_id,
       folder_id = (SELECT folder_id FROM folders WHERE name = $folder)
```

I've mixed SQL and PHP there, so that's not working code, but it should give you what you need.

Comment: This is very intuitive, will require more work than one table, but I guess it's not so bad. How do I 'tag' by the way? I'm rpetty sure I know what you mean, but just in case...

Comment: @user657, I'd also STRONGLY recommend refactoring your code. Consider looking into PHP frameworks, or even an ORM (object-relational-mapper). It will let you write data access code without having to worry too much about SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means... From the very beginning, I told myself to learn php only to create this website I had in mind. I'm very close to the end now. Would it still be worth learning for some reasons I don't know? Will it make my workflow faster, even though the only thing I'm probably going to be doing after I figure this out, would be uploading images via MySQL and typicable blogging stuff, and not code that much?

Comment: A "tag" would be a row in `Folders`.  To tag an image, you'd put a row into `Image_Folders`, connecting the image to some folder.  In this way, you can connect multiple images to multiple folders.  As opposed to my answer (presenting a "one-to-many" relationship), this is a "many-to-many" relationship.

Comment: @user657, absolutely not. If you're near the end, and you don't plan to invest a lot of time building it 'bigger and better', then don't bother with the framework/orm. One thing to be aware of when crafting SQL in code that contains user input is SQL Injection attacks. If you have those covered, you're all set.

Comment: @user657, that means if there are ANY URL query strings that are used to build up queries, you are open to attack. Off topic, but worth considering. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to have more then one table most of the time, so that data isn't repeated, this is called normalisation, in your example you want to tables:

1. tblImages
2. tblGalleries
3. tblImages

   - thumbnailID, link, picture, alt, time, galleryID
4. tblGalleries

   - galleryID, galleryName

They contain a link to each other, this is the key (primary key in tblGalleries and the foreign key of tblImages).

My preference would be to create a 'stored procedure' or simply 'procedure' in MySQL, in MySQL this would look like this:

> CREATE PROCEDURE spImage_Update @link
>   varchar(50), @picture varchar(50),
>   @alt varchar(50), @galleryID int
>
> AS BEGIN
>
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>
> INSERT INTO tblImages  VALUES (@link,
>   @picture, @alt, @galleryID)
>
> END

- By setting the gallery ID you can say which gallery you want it to be in.

When you want to select all images, write your query as such...

> SELECT * FROM tblImages

When you want a specific gallery just your query as...

> 'SELECT * FROM tblImages WHERE
>   GalleryID = 1' or 'SELECT * FROM
>   tblImages WHERE GalleryID =
>   @GalleryID'

- in a SP.

Where exactly are you stuck.